# TypeScript: TS2339 error -- Property does not exist on type 'object'

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-types, typescript-3.6

I am having trouble resolving this error on my app.
Essentially, I have an interface set as so:

```
interface skuInfo {
    href: string
}

interface myObjectItem {
    itemId: string
    isFound: boolean
    price: {
        selling: number 
    }
    images: {
        sku: skuInfo[]
    }
}
```

What trips me is the `myObjectItem.images.sku`.

I have an object set as so: `const exObj: myObjectItem`.

When I try to access its property:
`exObj.images.sku[0].href`, I receive the following error:

```
Property 'href' does not exist on type 'object'
```

In my Visual Code editor, I can see that it prefills the `href` attribute when accessing an array of the object, but TS is still complaining.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your interface, the property access should be

```js
exObj.images.sku[0].href
// -----------^
```

So, typescript is right, your images object doesn't have `href` property

Check this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ts=3.6.3&ssl=17&ssc=2&pln=17&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgM4GsCuBJEMD2yA3gFDLnIAWUEMAXGmFKAOYkC%20JJoksiKAWwCeAeQBGAKwgIw2SAOJkKwedgAmDVE1ZLywVADF8mEBuRj8%20ADYQ4IXcgAOzJA1IUPaCFausGITAExaGQHTg9gATgWCFQ3Bw8MTE0sXAIAbQBdMI4uBHwQLWQIAA9xCQZhculZeWQAXmJI6Ni3JIYs9gAaZH0jEzN4K1QIHpUIAXUGAHJpnudgV2IRnz9kAEZ2dgBuLhJS8oA6ZpjUQ6T0gAZMw%20paIA), your error won't reproduces.

Comment: Sorry, I've re-edited the original comments. 
Yes I meant `images.sku[0].href`, and it still gives me an error

Comment: I've added a playground